# How to fix 'No such module SQLite' on Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, sqlite

I am working on Swift 3 in an application that works with a local database, the problem is that when I type "import SQLite", I get this error: "No such module SQLite"

I already tried to solve this problem using command in the terminal using "pod init" but I can not find a solution for this problem, I have not been able to implement SQLite frameworks

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ConexcionBD
//
//  Created by Barbatos on 5/2/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Seccion 15. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SQLite//Error al escribir esta parte del codigo

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I have not managed to use SQLite in XCode, how can I use the SQLite framework

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to import a non-existent framework or module, which is that `SQLite`. What you want is a wrapper for `SQLite`. iOS does not have that, but there's an open-sourced project for that. It's called FMDB.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSCore/FMDB

This is an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite: http://sqlite.org/

Even though you're using Swift, you could easily port that Objective-C wrapper codes into your Swift project.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but I already managed to solve the problem, I was doing my procedures wrong to install the SQLite3 pod from the console, but I solved it by updating the gems and watching the following tutorial:
https://www.efectoapple.com/tutorial-de-introduccion-cocoapods/